# Unable to connect to my node.js server remotely, running on Osx Mavericks

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, osx-mavericks

I have studied 25+ articles here, about possible reasons why I can't  connect to my node.js webserver running on an iMac (osx Mavericks).

I have set up my test project successfully, it works great on localhost (port 3000). Than I place the index.html file on a remote server (website) where it was meant to be, but it won't connect any more to my home computer running the Node.js server.

I have:
- double checked everything
- turned off firewalls
- tried to bind the port (3000) to '0.0.0.0'
- switched from my home wifi to my mobile cellular internet (to be sure the router could not block my ports)
- tried changing the listener port to: 8080, 8888, 80, 3000, etc...
- etc.

Help would greatly be appreciated, otherwise I think I give up...

If I do netstats, this is what I get:

```
tcp4       0      0  *.3000                 *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  *.17500                *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.17603        *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.17600        *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp46      0      0  *.7348                 *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp46      0      0  *.7347                 *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  *.3234                 *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.5.3233       *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  *.88                   *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  *.22                   *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.631          *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  *.445                  *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  *.5900                 *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  *.548                  *.*                    LISTEN
```

server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var clients =[];


app.use("/www", express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/whiteboard.html');
});


io.on('connection', function(socket){

     console.info('New client connected (id=' + socket.id + ').');

});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

index.html (website)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO Webpage</title>


    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">


    var url = 'http://109.166.x.x:3000';    

    var socket = io.connect(url);

    socket.on('moving', function (data) {

        if(! (data.id in clients)){

            // a new user has come online. 

        }       

    });     

    </script>
</head>
  <body>   



  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is difficult for people to remotely diagnose because it likely has to do with the configuration of your home network and how it connects to your internet connection (none of which you have disclosed) and what exactly is accepted for incoming connections and then what happens to those incoming connections. The usual configuration requires that you configure port forwarding from your cable modem or dsl modem (which is the device that actually has your public-facing IP address) to your local computer so that incoming connections that arrive at the cable modem are then forwarded to your iMac.

Comment: @jfriend00 right, this is why I have switched to my cellular connection (3g), to avoid complications caused by a router. In this moment there is no router between the internet and my pc.

Comment: Uhhh, I rather doubt your cellular connection is just sitting on the internet with full access for incoming connections.  It has infrastructure in front of it too.  At least with your cable modem, you can control its configuration.  I'd suggest you run a tracert from your remote device to the IP address and see where the packets start getting blocked.

Comment: @jfriend00 - :(  I will try to dig deeper into its NAT settings. thanks...